# Task for changing the AndroidTest runner

Tags: android, testing, gradle, automated-tests, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to setup a task that will setup a different runner in the android gradle plugin.

My idea is to have something like:

```
./gradlew differentRunner connectedAndroidTest
```

That would run androidTests with a different runner.

What I have so far:

```
task differentRunner << {
    project.android.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner = "com.example.DifferentRunner"
    println 'Different runner set.'
}
```

But, even though I see the log printed when issuing the above mentioned command, tests are run with the runner set in defaultConfig.

How could I achieve this?

P.S. I know I could use flavours, but those are just not an option for me, I would like to setup a custom task.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you don't want to use flavors etc to accomplish this, but if you're flexible on using a custom task then properties may be a viable option.

`testInstrumentationRunner project.hasProperty('customRunner') ? 'com.example.DifferentRunner' : 'default runner'`

and then to run using custom runner:

`./gradlew -PcustomRunner connectedAndroidTest`